# Bresenham line drawer crashes after certain loop before rendering anything?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, bresenham

I am trying to draw histogram using Bresenham Line drawing algorithm using OpenGL in CodeBlocks. When arguments to drawLine are changed (manually/ hardcoded) the program crashes. The code is not complete and I am just trying to experiment around. Why is the program crashing after certain loop before rendering anything?

I have tried different argument within the drawLine function inside drawHistogram function. Also there seems problem with loop itself. I can't work my head around there. Though the logic seems OK to me, the result is not quite as expected.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glut.h>

using namespace std;

void drawLine();
void inputData();
void CoordinateAxes();
void plot(float x, float y);

void drawBar(float );
void drawHistogram();

float x, y, dx, dy, D1, D2, xInc, yInc;

//int frequency[5] = {100, 200, 150, 300, 500} ;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //inputData();

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);

    glutCreateWindow("DDA Algorithm");
    glutDisplayFunc(drawHistogram);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}

void drawLine(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    CoordinateAxes();
    glColor3ub(255 ,255,255);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);

        dx = x2 - x1;
        dy = y2 - y1;

        float P[int(dx)];

        if (dy >= dx)
        {
            D1 = dx;
            D2 = dy;
            xInc = 0;
            yInc = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            D1 = dy;
            D2 = dx;
            xInc = 1;
            yInc = 0;
        }

        P[0] = 2*D1 - D2;


        x = x1;
        y = y1;
        //plot(x, y);
        //cout << "(" << x << "," << y << ") ";
        //cout << D2;



        for(int i = 0; i < D2 ; i++)
        {
            if (P[i] <= 0)
            {
                plot(x , y);
                P[i+1] = P[i] + 2*D1;
                x += xInc;
                y += yInc;
                //cout << "(" << x << "," << y << ")";
            }
            else
            {
                plot(x , y );
                P[i+1] = P[i] + 2*D1 - 2*D2;
                x += 1;
                y += 1;
                //cout << "(" << x << "," << y << ")";
            }
        }
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

//void inputData()
//{
//    cout << "Enter frequencies of 5 data: ";
//
//    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
//    {
//        cin >> freq[i];
//    }
//}

void CoordinateAxes()
{
    glColor3ub(0,0,255);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2f(0,1);
        glVertex2f(0,-1);
        glVertex2f(-1,0);
        glVertex2f(1,0);
    glEnd();
}

void plot(float x, float y)
{
    glVertex2f(x/500, y/500);
    cout << "(" << x << "," << y << ")";
}

//void drawBar(float freq)
//{
//    drawLine(0, 0, 0, freq );
//    drawLine(0, freq, 25, freq);
//    drawLine(25, freq, 25, 0);
//}

void drawHistogram()
{
    drawLine(10, 10, 10, 100 );
}
```

I expect a straight line to be rendered on OpenGL window.

Comment: In which line does it crash? Which error do you get? Also: when you are using OpenGL, whats the point of implementing your own line-drawing? OpenGL can already draw lines.

Comment: When you call `drawLine(10, 10, 10, 100 )` then `x1=10` and `x2=10` so `dx=0`because of `dx = x2 - x1;` and finally the array `P` has size 0  `float P[int(dx)];` Probably it has to be `float P[int(std::max(abs(dx)+0.5, abs(dy)+0.5))+1]`

Answer (score 1):

The issue start at the line

> ```
> drawLine(10, 10, 10, 100 )
> ```

This call causes that `x1=10` and `x2=10`, so `dx=0` because of `dx = x2 - x1;`
Finally the array `P` has size 0,because of  `float P[int(dx)];`

> ```
> void drawLine(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
> {
>     // [...]
>
>     dx = x2 - x1;
>     dy = y2 - y1;
>
>     float P[int(dx)];
> ```

You've to create an array with the size of the absolut maximum difference of `x2-x1` and `y2-y1`:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
```

```cpp
float P[int(std::max(abs(dx), abs(dy))+0.5)+1];
```

In c++ I recommend to use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/):

```cpp
#include <vector>
```

```cpp
std::vector<float> P(int(std::max(abs(dx), abs(dy))+0.5)+1, 0.0f);
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes the problem was with the array. Now it works fine.